# How to fire trigger in SQL Server if in a same row 2 column value are same?

Tags: sql-server

How to fire trigger in SQL Server if in a row 2 column values are the same?

In my table there are 3 columns `id`, `capacity`, `taken` and the table has some rows. If `taken` is equal to `capacity`, then trigger should fire. I wrote the trigger shown below, but it says "subquery returned more than 1 value" - this is not permitted.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[sectionTrigger1]
ON [dbo].[tblTestCapacity]
FOR UPDATE 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF (SELECT (Capacity-SeatTaken) FROM tblTestCapacity) = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tblTest(sectionid, courseid, seatcapacity, seattaken)
            SELECT sectionid, courseid, seatcapacity, seattaken 
            FROM tblTest 
    END
END
```

Comment: Firstly let me know, 
1. you want to restrict duplicate rows ?
or 
2. values of 2 columns in single row?

for 1. you can use if exists(), 
for 2. there is no solution, you cannot check any thing before insert... you can achieve this by doing some complex query, but it is not necessary at Insert...

Comment: @SarveshBandekar option 1 can be done very easy with a unique index, no need for any query. Option 2 can be done with very simple query in insert/update trigger. No need for anything complex

Comment: I want option 2. Can u please help?

Comment: @Md.RayhanKhan the code in my answer can be used for option 2. The select query there will return all rows where Capacity and SeatTaken have the same value. If you need this on other columns please edit your question and explain as clear as possible

Comment: @Md.RayhanKhan I updated my answer for option 2

Comment: You can also add a check constraint on the table and avoid the trigger.

Comment: I updated my answer again, with an example of a constraint as suggested by @EzLo

Comment: Third recommendation to use a CHECK constraint, not a trigger. Always avoid triggers where possible

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Agree fully on that. It was not clear what the OP wanted when I wrote my answer, I have added this option as the best option now

Comment: I totally understand - wasn't referring to your answer... here's an upvote :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

inside a trigger you should use the `inserted` table, which will hold all updated rows

something like this maybe ?

```
INSERT INTO tblTest(sectionid, courseid, seatcapacity, seattaken)
SELECT i.sectionid, i.courseid, i.seatcapacity, i.seattaken 
FROM   inserted i
where  (i.Capacity - i.SeatTaken) = 0
```

notice you dont need the `IF` anymore because it is already in the `WHERE` clause

EDIT
IF you want to do something else when `(i.Capacity - i.SeatTaken) = 0` you can use the same query

```
if exists ( SELECT i.sectionid, i.courseid, i.seatcapacity, i.seattaken 
            FROM   inserted i
            where  (i.Capacity - i.SeatTaken) = 0
          )
begin
     -- do here your code if any row exists with this condition
     -- you could for example throw an exception here
     THROW 51000, 'your message here.', 1;
end
```

**EDIT**
if your goal is to restrict 2 columns in the table from having the same value, you can also add a constraint.
This way you dont even need a trigger
**This is the best option, if all you need is prevent 2 columns from having the same value**

```
alter table tblTestCapacity
add constraint CH_Doubles check (Capacity <> SeatTaken)
```

if both or one column can be null, you have to add a little more

```
alter table tblTestCapacity
add constraint CH_Doubles check (isnull(Capacity, -1) <> isnull(SeatTaken, -1))
```

The last alter statement is not tested, not sure if sql-server allows this

Comment: Hi Actually it will insert at tblTest table if at  tblTestCapacity tables for same row Capacity and  SeatTaken value is same

Comment: Well I think you can pick from my answer what you need now

Comment: Hi you are right I just need to restrict for same value. But alter table tblTestCapacity
add constraint CH_Doubles check (Capacity <> SeatTaken) returns at sql server this error The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CH_Doubles". The conflict occurred in database "test", table "dbo.tblTestCapacity".

Comment: That means there are now rows in your table with duplicate values in these 2 columns. You will have to clear that up first before you can run the alter statement

Comment: It also means that the constraint will work perfect, once the alter statement can be run

Comment: Also, consider naming the constraint better, I used CH_Doubles but I am sure you can come up with a better name that means more to you then this

Comment: Thanks a lot. U just saved my research time . ur solution was very silly but i was doing very complicated things by applying trigger. Thanks a lot man. Learned a new thing.